# Meteor: Using while loop in Template

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

How would I use a while loop in meteor blaze?
I tried using `{{unless}}` but that did not work. 
This is what I tried:

```
<template name="homePage">
    <h2>Welcome to home page! </h2>
    {{#unless numberOfDays 0}}
        <span>hi</span>
        {{numberOfDays--}}
    {{/#unless}}
</template>
```

It did not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

**There is** **no #while in spacebars**, the templating engine that is default in meteor-blaze.

The `#unless` keyword is a negated `#if`, a conditional on something not being truthy. The unless block is not a loop, it can only run once.  Like if, the block will either run or not run.  The #unless runs if the condition is not truthy.

The only loop construct is #each.   You could emulate the behavior of a for or while loop by calculating the results outside the template and placing them in an array variable.  In the template, call #each on the array variable.

Although writing a customized [handlebars block helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html) can be used to make custom iteration such as a while loop, Meteor's spacebars is a fork of the handlebars code, and may require a slightly different syntax.

For most simple uses, #each is enough .  Reformatting data will often allow #each to be used in a natural way.

## From the [Spacebar docs](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md)

## #Each

An #each template tag takes a sequence argument and inserts its content for each item in the sequence, setting the data context to the value of that item:

`<ul>
{{#each people}}
  <li>{{name}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>`

The argument is typically a Meteor cursor (the result of collection.find(), for example), but it may also be a plain JavaScript array, null, or undefined.

An "else" section may be provided, which is used (with no new data context) if there are zero items in the sequence at any time.